# Shall we make [manners] synonym to [etiquette] or [courtesy]?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of now, there is only one question for [manners](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manners)

[Who should identify themself first on the phone: the caller or the person called?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/who-should-identify-themself-first-on-the-phone-the-caller-or-the-person-called)

I think this tag can be a synonym to [etiquette](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) or [courtesy](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/courtesy).

Or is there any difference that requires [manners](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manners) to have its own tag?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53009/what-is-the-difference-between-manners-and-etiquette